# How to set different failover priority to nodes AWS Aurora cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on creating a template for Aurora RDS clusters using terraform, RDS clusters will be global multi-AZ with 3 nodes in primary region and 2 nodes in secondary region.

passing value for “promotion_tier” will set the failover priority but it is going to be same for all nodes.

I am looking for a way to set different failover priority for 3 nodes in primary region, can this be accomplished with terraform.
when i set a value in this template it is applied to all nodes, is there a way to set different value to each node

Code block from main.tf

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "default" {
  count                   = "${local.enabled ? var.cluster_size : 0}"
  identifier              = "${module.label.id}-${count.index+1}"
  cluster_identifier      = "${var.cluster_identifier}"
  engine                  = "${local.engine}"
  instance_class          = "${var.instance_type}"
  db_subnet_group_name    = "${local.db_subnet_group_name}"
  db_parameter_group_name = "${join("", aws_db_parameter_group.default.*.name)}"
  publicly_accessible     = "${var.publicly_accessible}"
  promotion_tier          = "${var.promotion_tier}"
  tags                    = "${module.label.tags}"
  monitoring_interval     = "${var.rds_monitoring_interval}"
  monitoring_role_arn     = "${var.rds_monitoring_role_arn}"
```

code block from variables.tf

```
variable "promotion_tier" {   
description = "Failover Priority setting on instance level. The reader who has lower tier has higher priority to get promoted to writer (values can range from 0-15)."   
default = "2" 
}
```

Thanks
Jag

Answer (score 1):

Make your variable a list (and stop representing numbers as strings):

```
variable "promotion_tier" {   
  description = "Failover Priority setting on instance level. The reader who has lower tier has higher priority to get promoted to writer (values can range from 0-15)."   
  type = list(number)
  default = [2, 1, 3] # Whatever you want your promotion tier values to be
}
```

Now use those values (note that you don't have to surround every value with "${
}", you haven't had to do that in Terraform for a long time now):

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "default" {
  count                   = local.enabled ? var.cluster_size : 0
  identifier              = "${module.label.id}-${count.index+1}"
  promotion_tier          = var.promotion_tier[count.index]
```

You just need to make sure your list of promotion tier values is the same size as the `var.cluster_size` value, or you will get an error. If that's a problem, you could also have a default promotion tier value if you have more cluster instances than you have promotion tiers:

```
# Default to a promotion_tier value of 1, for instances created after we run out of var.promotion_tier values
promotion_tier = length(var.promotion_tier) > count.index ? var.promotion_tier[count.index] : 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, i was able to set different priority for each node now.